# How to translate "logo" to Esperanto?

Tags: translation, single-word-requests

I've heard everything: *emblemo*, *ikono*, *logotipo*, *marko*, etc. I'd really love to have a general word that I can use like in English, but I'm doubtful that this exists in Esperanto. Is there any word that would be suitable for the same use?

**Update:** I somehow have the sense that the youth tend to use the word *logotipo*, while older speakers use *emblemo*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I always use *emblemo*. I've never used *ikono* or *logotipo*. I have on occasion used *varmarko* when talking more about a product.

Answer (score 2):

Why is *emblemo* not a general word that you can use like in English? ;-)

Comment: Laŭ la diskuto ĉe https://www.facebook.com/groups/konsultejo/permalink/1318271961531156/?match=bG9nbw%3D%3D mi havis la impreson, ke multaj ne kredis, ke "emblemo" povas havi tiom vastan signifon kiel la angla vorto "logo". Eble ĝi tamen taŭgas, kaj PIV havas tro limigitan difinon.

Comment: Jes, la PIV-a difino de "emblem/o" estas tro limiga. Mi jam de multaj jaroj ĉiam uzas "emblemo" por la angla "logo", kaj aŭdas multajn aliajn lingve spertajn Esperantistojn fari same.

Comment: @MarcosCramer ĉu vi ankaŭ ofte aŭdis "logotipo" de lingve spertaj esperantistoj?

Comment: PIV ĉiam iomete postrestas. Mi kredas, ke „emblemo” estas plej ofte uzata en la ĉiutaga lingvo.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/633)

Comment: @kiamlaluno I think that you didn’t understand my answer ;-) It means of course that „emblemo” is the right word.

Comment: Then write it as sentence. As it is written, it is a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Logotipo estas bona, en tio kio enhavas ambaŭ ideoj de la esperanta senco de logo, psika objekto de altiro, k tipo.  Logomarko egale taŭgas laŭ mi.

Comment: _LOGOTIP'_ estas unu radiko, ĝi ne estas kunmetita el _LOG'_ kaj _TIP'_.